# Strange problem getting $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}

Tags: perl, apache, fastcgi, httprequest, varnish

I'm having a strange problem here. I'm moving a (working) site to a new apache server to which I don't have direct access (I have to go through two people to get stuff done).

The site uses a perl script called adframe to parse html templates. The URLs with which it's called look like `/cgi-bin/adframe/index.html?x=something` with `adframe` being the script. The missing suffix never caused any real problems. But on this new Ubuntu server `$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}` is always empty. `$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'}` shows up correctly as GET, but the query_string shows nothing ...

Regular *.cgi scripts show the query_string without problems.

From the logs I gathered that the server seems to be running fastcgi, mod_fcgid and the server doesn't even accept .pl as an extension for scripts. I don't have that much experience with server software, but I figured it might be a problem with the server not accepting adframe as a cgi script and thus not passing the query_string correctly ... Can anyone give me a few hints to where I could point the administrator or maybe something I could do in .htaccess myself? Anyway to make sure, `adframe` is recognized as a cgi script!? (if that's the problem ...)

Any help is appreciated!
thomas

EDIT: I found more details: The server seems to be running a VARNISH cache ... thats's the main difference to my usual configurations ...
Also, the way the script works is, if you call /cgi-bin/adframe/somedir/somefile.html?x=something, $ENV{PATH_INFO} tells which template to parse and $ENV{QUERY_STRING} is, well, the query string. Now the query string is empty, but if I call /cgi-bin/adframe?x=something (without any PATH_INFO), the query string shows up!
Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?
thanks!

Comment: Does it actually get executed? (e.g. does it return an error, or run correctly as if it was called with no parameters)? Also, what happens if you send the server a matching POST request?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hints. Yes, it gets executed as if no parameters were passed and yes, POST reaches the script (via STDIN) ...

Comment: I also just tried $cgi->param() to get the query string. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The VARNISH cache strips all the query strings off static content (*.html etc) ... phew

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem. I am complete newbie in perl scripting.

I tried following:

```
@values = split (/&/, $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'});
```

but it didn`t work

this worked:

```
@values = split (/&/, "$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}");
```

just in case if other newbies have ran into the same problem.